# How to insert a column?

Tags: sql

How to insert a column while working on an already created table, like if we get to need a column in a particular table?

Help

Comment: What are you using? Do you have tooling on your db of do you want it to work from a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `alter table` SQL DDL command.

Its exact syntax will depend on the RDBMS you are using, but it will usually be something like:

```
alter table your_table add column new_column varchar(200);
```

*assuming you want to add a new column named `new_column` of `varchar(200)` type.*

Comment: The column will need to be nullable or have a default assigned if the table contains data.